# MySql | How to compute every row in same table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this table

```
Grade   Lec    Lab
1.50       3      0
1.50       3      0
1.50       2      1
```

The formula will be

1.50 * 3
1.50 * 3
1.50 * (2 + 1) = 13.5

The results will divide to total number of lec and lab it will be 13.5 / 9 = 1.5

Comment: What do you exactly want to add? Do you want to add grades and then divide by Lec and Lab?

Comment: I want to add every row example grade and lec and lab in row 1 will add 1 + 3 + 0 then next one 2 + 3 + 0 then 3 + 2 + 1 after that the total is 15 then it will divide to the total number of lec and lab which is 9

Comment: Please update your post to clarify that point. Best of all, please add the expected output for your example, with an explanation how that output is supposed to be achieved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the total sum of `grades`, `lec` and `lab` and divide that by the total sum of `lec` and `lab`?

```
SELECT (SUM(Grade) + SUM(Lec) + SUM(Lab)) /  (SUM(Lec) + SUM(Lab))
FROM grades;
```

**Result:**

```
1.6667
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fb829c2be7962f413357f7954a2f393c)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should solve your problem:

```
SELECT SUM(Grade + Lec + Lab) / 
       SUM(Lec + Lab) AS result 
FROM grades
```

If you do this calculation often, you may wish to define them as generated columns:

```
CREATE TABLE grades
(
    Grade INT NOT NULL,
    Lec INT NOT NULL,
    Lab INT NOT NULL,
    RowTotal INT AS (Grade + Lec + Lab),
    LecLabTotal INT AS (Lec + Lab)
);
```

Then getting the values simply becomes:

```
SELECT SUM(RowTotal) / SUM(LecLabTotal) AS Total
  FROM grades;
```

Depending on the number of rows per table you can also opt to persist the result of the generated columns using the `STORED` keyword. This can improve performance at the cost of more storage space. It is up to you based on your requirements to decide which one is best.

You can find more information in the [MySQL Documentarion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Generated columns will give close to nothing - anycase calculation of two SUM() over all data array needed, this is fullscan, and additional separate values summarizing overhead is close to negligible.